# Variable Capture and For-Loop Arithmetic

Tags: bash, awk

My input files are a single column with variable length of rows. My code is supposed to count those rows, and print a specified number. The problem I'm having, is if the number of rows captured in the variable "A" is less than 1, I want it to print at least 1 row so the output file isn't empty. If "A" (1% of the total number of rows) is greater than 1, I want to print that number of rows. My hybrid awk-bash code looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in {1..2}
do
input="../ExpressionSet_"$i"_chunk.txt"
    for j in {1..2}
do

A=$(awk 'END{print NR*0.01}' $input)
Y=1
X=0
if (( "$A" -lt "$Y")); then
X=$A+1
else
X=$A

fi
awk 'NR<='$X' {print $0}' $input > "$i"_top1pc.txt

B=$(awk 'END{print NR*0.05}' $input) 
awk 'NR<='$B' {print $0}' $input > "$i"_top5pc.txt
```

Confusingly, I keep getting error messages like

```
thresholdSelector_pc.sh: line 20: ((: 0.24 -lt 1: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".24 -lt 1")
thresholdSelector_pc.sh: line 20: ((: 47.24 -lt 1: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".24 -lt 1")
```

By the way, inputFile1 has 24 lines and inputFile2 has 4724 lines. Thanks for the help!

Comment: AFAIK `-lt` isn't a valid arithmetic operator inside `(( ... ))` - and bash only performs integer arithmetic anyhow. Can you not do what you want *within* awk?

Comment: I tried to use "<" but the program reads it as a redirection character.

Answer (score 2):

I think your root problem is that you tried to use bash syntax in an sh script. Bash defines extensions to the sh common denominator; if you want to use bash-specific features, your script must start with `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`.

Sh doesn't have the `((…))` syntax for arithmetic expressions. But you don't need it here, you can use the portable `[ … ]` conditional syntax. In the `[ … ]` conditional, the “less than” operator is written `-lt`.

Braces `{1..2}` are another bash feature that doesn't exist in sh. Another bug in your script is `X=$A+1`, which sets `X` to a string like `42+1` if the value of `A` is `42`; to perform an arithmetic calculation, you need to use the arithmetic expression syntax `$((…))`.

Also, as a general remark, [always use double quotes around variable substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).

Another problem with your code is that it looks like `A` is a decimal number. Shell arithmetic only works with integers. I've adapted the algorithm but check what it does, I might not have rounded the way you intended. Using awk just to count the number of lines is overkill, `wc -l` is a clearer and faster way of doing that. Similarly, to print the first N lines of a file, just call `head`.

Yet another bug is that `$i_chunk` is the value of the variable `i_chunk`. To take the value of `i` and append `_chunk`, you need to delimit the variable name with braces: `${i}_chunk`.

I have no idea what the loop on `j` is supposed to be doing, I've left it alone.

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in 1 2
do
  input="../ExpressionSet_${i}_chunk.txt"
  for j in 1 2
  do
    A=$(wc -l <"$input")
    Y=100
    X=0
    if [ "$A" -lt "$Y" ]; then
      X=$((A+100))
    else
      X=$A
    fi
    head -n "$((X/100))" "$input" > "$i"_top1pc.txt
    head -n "$((X/20))" "$input" > "$i"_top5pc.txt
  done
done
```

If you choose to write a bash script, you can make use of several bash features:

- `((…))` for arithmetic evaluations (but still integer only)
- `typeset -i` to declare an integer variable, so that assigning an arithmetic expression evaluates it

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 1 2
do
  input="../ExpressionSet_${i}_chunk.txt"
  for j in 1 2
  do
    A=$(wc -l <"$input")
    Y=100
    typeset -i X
    if ((A < Y)); then
      X=A+100
    else
      X=$A
    fi
    head -n "$((X/100))" "$input" > "$i"_top1pc.txt
    head -n "$((X/20))" "$input" > "$i"_top5pc.txt
  done
done
```

Comment: You could go a bit further with the conditional operator: `X=$((A < Y ? A + 100 : A))`.